# Choose 1 from each of 11 ArrayLists is too slow

Tags: java, combinations, cartesian-product

This is basically what my program is doing:

if you have 5 different shirts and 4 different pants to choose from, there are 20 different combinations of shirts and pants you can wear, and my program would iterate through all 20 combinations to determine which is the "best" to wear.

Except, in my situation, there are 11 different types of clothing (such as headgear, gloves, pants, earrings, shoes, cloak, etc) and as many as 10 items in each category. So, there could be as many as 11^10 combinations, and when I tried running my program with only 4 in each category, or 11^4, it took about 5 seconds to complete. 11^10 will take DAYS.

Currently, what I have going on is 11 for loops nested inside each other to go through every combination. This obviously isn't the best way to do this because it is so slow. How can I make this faster? For context, I have 1 "outer" ArrayList containing 11 ArrayLists, and each of those 11 ArrayLists is a list of objects (the clothing).

Comment: Just curious, but what if you tried doing this with arrays rather than ArrayLists. But regardless, you're looping a lot, so it's not unexpected for this to take a bit of time to achieve.

Comment: How do you determine what is "best?"

Comment: btw, you have your exponent and bases mixed up.  it should be 10^11 and 4^11, i.e., with 11 different categories with 4 items in each the total number of combinations is 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 = 4^11, not 11^4.

Comment: This program is essentially a calculator for gear in the video game that put together will give me the best stats. So, for example, a piece of armor gives 5 of str, 8 of dex, and 3 of int. Each armor is different. I add up each respective stat for a set of armor that contains 11 pieces of armor, and then add up the totals of str, dex, and int. The set that has the highest overall total is the "best". Since this is just addition and stuff, I feel like it doesn't contribute heavily to the time.

Comment: Oh you're right, I mixed up the exponents. Still, it's going to take way too much time to execute my program. 10^11/4^11=23842, and since 4^11 took about 5 seconds, 10^11 would take about 33 hours. :(

Comment: If cost is no object, then simply take the best item of each category.  If cost is important, then take the most cost effective item from each category, then go back and choose the best upgrade (best for cost) over all the categories that you can afford until you've spent all your money.  Note you could use some other data structures to keep the cost-adjusted values in sorted order to speed up the process by only having to check the top item in each category to compare each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way of doing it without using a brute-force search, however you can chop down the choice area by generating a range of possible matches, and only iterating through the items in the list that are in that range.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Since your score is additive, the best item of clothing from each category is the one that gives the best sum of dex+str+int. This means that you don't need to consider combinations, just pick the best shirt, then the best pants, etc. So 11 loops, not 11 nested loops.

**Old answer**

In the general case, there brute force (what you're doing right now) is the only way to guarantee a correct answer.

Under some conditions, however, you can do better: For example if I know that if the one shirt-pants combination is "better" than another shirt-pants combination no matter what other items of clothing I choose, I can find the best shirt-pants combination first, and then consider what item of clothing is best to add to it. It's essentially a greedy search.

Comment: Hmm, that actually might work. But now that you bring that up, I guess I should be a little more specific about the exact algorithm, because I see a potential problem. The game will mitigate stats past a certain amount. So for example, after you have a total of 50 of str from your armor, each additional str from armor actually only gives 0.5 str. And also, after you reach a mitigated str of 65 (or unmitigated of 80 because of the 0.5 multiplier), you cannot receive any additional str from your armor. I'm having difficulty thinking about how I could work this into your method.

Comment: Actually, just kidding, I think I figured it out. I just have to keep track of the totals of each stat, and if it goes above that number, future pieces of clothing won't contribute to that certain stat, but the other stats will still go to the total. That math will work out to be the same as what I had before... I hope.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's that simple in this case... suppose you have only shirts and pants, you have one shirt that's +50str, one shirt that's +20str, +20dex, and only one pair of pants that is +30str, +30dex. If you pick the shirt first, you'll pick the wrong one.

Comment: This type of problem is amenable to a technique called "[Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)". The theory goes back to the 1940's and earlier, and there are well-established algorithms for finding maxima (or minima) based on multiple criteria. The general problem is (I believe) theorized to be NP-complete (i.e. computationally hard) but many actual instances are easily solvable.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I'm pretty sure linear programming is polynomial. The problem here is that this is an integer linear program, which *is* NP-complete.